# Is there any other fuel to power my ship?

Tags: starbound

I'm stuck on a astriod and there is no oxygen so I die really fast I can't mine fast enough help.I've tried coal but I don't have enough.

Comment: I can't recall how exactly, but I think there is a way to convert/burn wood into fuel. Have you tried that?

Comment: thanks but i dont have enough wood either

Comment: You can join any multiplayer server with this character, you will spawn on other planet. Collect coal/wood, then again start singleplayer. Contents of your inventory/ship is shared between multiplayer and singleplayer.

Comment: You can also warp to other planets in the same area for 1 fuel instead of the normal amount. Unless the only thing in the area is asteroids and/or moons, you should be able to find a hospitable planet to harvest coal from.